# How to create custom UIViewAnimation

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, xcode4.5, uiviewanimation

What is the simplest way to create a custom UIView animation transition? Most of the tutorials that pop up in a Google search are not recent. (I'm using XCode 4.5 version) In my current iPhone app I have the following code for my screen transitions:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"View flip" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.25];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view                            cache:YES];    
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I want something unique instead of the 5 or 6 built-in transitions. Any ideas or suggestions on where to start?

Comment: First of all, don't use old methods, like the ones you show in your question. Use the block based methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    //Move frame or transform view
}];
```

Inside that block you can put arbitrary animation code.

Comment: Very nice! I'll go and play around from here!